# When I delete the last line in a file i get a blank line PHP

Tags: php, arrays, file, line

Hi im having a problem rewriting to a file. When i delete the last line in a file and rewrite the array back to a temp file i get a blank like at the end that messes up other files in a project.

This is the contacts text file

```
1|Mr.|Blank|Blank|||||||||
2|Mr.|Blank2|Blank2|||||||||
3|Mr.|Blank3|Blank3|||||||||
```

this is the code for the delete

```
<?php


    $select = 3;


    $tempFilename = 'contacts_temp';
    touch($tempFilename);

    $file_name = "contacts";
    $file = fopen($file_name, "r+")or exit("Unable to open file!");

    $tempfile = fopen($tempFilename, "r+")or exit("Unable to open file!");


    for($c=0;!feof($file);$c++)
    {
        $top = fgets($file);
        $contactsArray[$c] = $top;
    }

    for ($d=0; $d!=count($contactsArray);$d++){
            //echo $usersArray[$d];
            $tempusersArray[$d] = explode('|', $contactsArray[$d]);
    }

    rewind($tempfile);
    for ($c=0;$c<count($contactsArray);$c++){
        if($tempusersArray[$c][0]==$select){
            unset($contactsArray[$c]);
        }elseif($contactsArray[$c]==NULL){
            unset($contactsArray[$c]);
            break;
        }else{
            trim($contactsArray[$c]);
        }
    }

    var_dump($contactsArray);

    file_put_contents($tempFilename,$contactsArray);

?>
```

When this runs I would get a file back like this

```
1|Mr.|Blank|Blank|||||||||
2|Mr.|Blank2|Blank2|||||||||
//There would be a blank line here
```

Thanks is advance!

Answer (score 0):

In your contacts text file lines 1 and 2 end with a line break (\n), line 3 doesn't. So, if you delete line 3, the file will end with a line break and therefore show an empty line. If you delete line 1 or 2, the 3rd line without line break stays and you don't get an extra empty line. Either you add a line break to each end of line and deal with the empty line or you remove the line break in the last element of the array, which you write to disk.